# memory error in sklearn's pipeline

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I make a pipeline in my code like this

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
        ('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, min_df=10)),
        ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='log', n_jobs=-1)),
])
```

When I started to fit this pipeline on my data (about 1.4M of sentence), I see fast and huge increasing of RAM using.

After this increasing my kernel became dead. I suppose, this happens because sparse matrix after applying TfidfVectorizer has transformation to dense matrix. But SGDClassifier works with sparse matrix, isn't it?

Why this happens and what I can do in this case?

my versions:
(
python 2.7,
sklearn 0.18.1,
scipy 0.18.1,
numpy 1.12.0
)

Comment: Show the full stack trace of error

Comment: @VivekKumar I use python notebook and haven't error. I see that using RAM go to limit and just have message in Ipython Notebook "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Comment: Then try to use the code without the pipeline, ie first fit in tfidf and then fit in sgd. This way you can pinpoint where the memory increase is.

Answer (score 0):

I make the mistake and this code runs good without memory leak.